# ¿Como obtengo todas las coordenadas de mi evento touch?

Tags: java, android

El problema es que obtengo una gran parte de las coordenadas, pero si hago muy rápido el movimiento del touch pues me trae menos coordenadas que si lo pasara lento, no se si ponerlo en un hilo el proceso o algo parecido?
No se si ese sea el problema o traigo mal las coordenadas.

Este es el código:

```
final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {

    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {

        datosx.add(event.getHistoricalX(p,h));
        datosy.add(event.getHistoricalY(p,h));
    }
}

for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {

    datosx.add(event.getX(p));
    datosy.add(event.getY(p));
}
```

---

Jorgesys

Tengo esto: que realmente es todo lo que saco desde que se hace el touch down, touch move y touch up:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    datosx.add(event.getX());
                    datosy.add(event.getY());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                    final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                    for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {

                        for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {

                            datosx.add(event.getHistoricalX(p, h));
                            datosy.add(event.getHistoricalY(p, h));
                        }
                    }

                    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {

                        datosx.add(event.getX(p));
                        datosy.add(event.getY(p));
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    datosx.add(event.getX());
                    datosy.add(event.getY());
                    break;
            }
```

y de lo que pones, por que utilizas:

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK
```

y:

```
rootLayout.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas registrar todos los eventos touch al mover tu dedo, lo adecuado sería detectar el evento `ACTION_MOVE` de esta forma se registraría todos los puntos

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i(TAG, "Position: (x: " +  X +" , y:" + Y +")");

            //Registra puntos.
            datosx.add(X);
            datosy.add(Y);

            break;
    }
    rootLayout.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Solo debes ser consciente que de esta forma tu array ocupara más espacio en memoria.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final static String TAG = "Puntos";
    private RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    private List<Integer> datosx = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> datosy = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root);

        rootLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setText("Position: (x: " +  X +" , y:" + Y +")");

                datosx.add(X);
                datosy.add(Y);

                break;
        }
        rootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jorgesys.drawrectangle.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Move the rectangle!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Este es otro ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-DragDrop

Comment: por favor lee mi otra pregunta por favor...